# How do I stop two gameobjects from going through each other on unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have tried every from unchecking the matrix box , and removing the sphere collider . The problem I am having is the gameobjects wont stop going through each other .I dont know what is going on . I have a pic of what is going on : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq2Eb.png)

Comment: Why would you remove sphere collider?  How many colliders are there? If you tick the `Trigger` it makes it penetratable.  There is penetration factor related to velocity. High velocity ignores collision sometimes. You may need multiple colliders with your npcs.

Comment: how are you moving you gameobject(s)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't remove the colliders and make sure they are not set on Is Trigger (that makes the collider penetrable). Also, you are using sphere collider for quite a complex mesh, so I'd recommend using MeshCollider, which would generate it according to the mesh.

Secondly, recheck how you move the objects. If given too much force, it might bash through another collider and not get out of it (imagine that you breaking through a barrier and inside it you cannot get enough speed to break out of it again). That might happen if you use AddForce() and not increasing transform.velocity.

Thirdly, what controls these gameobjects? Player or NavMeshAgent? Because, I think, if they are controlled by AI (NavMeshAgent), they should avoid each other in their paths and shouldn't collide. However, I might be wrong on this one.

Comment: I don't have a nav mesh and everything is check. I have a script . I will try nav mesh.

Comment: I think simplest way  to avoid this is to use meshcollider if object geometry is uneven, otherwise avoid meshcollider, in case you are using meshcollider just remember, one of them should have rigidbody and convex option on meshcollider component should be tick